# In Kirkpatrick–Seidel algorithm, what happens if the median is exactly the point with largest Y coordinate?

Tags: computational-geometry, convex-hull

I have been trying to understand [Kirkpatrick–Seidel algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirkpatrick%E2%80%93Seidel_algorithm), which is an algorithm for computing the convex hull of a set of points in the plane with complexity O(nlog*h*) - where n is the number of input points and h is the number of points in the hull.
[The material I used](http://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1272&context=cis_reports) is quite simple and descriptive. But I've a doubt about the working of this algorithm in a special case.

While finding upper hull, After finding the medial line **L**, we define an upper bridge as a supporting line where all other points lie below it.

[image: Kirkpatrick–Seidel algorithm]

But how will we define this supporting line in the case where the median line just happened to be  passing through the point with largest Y coordinate?

Problem Image Here:

[image: Problem]

Answer (score 1):

In the event that there is a point whose `y` coordinate is strictly greater than all other points', and that point lies on the medial line, there are two possible choices for the upper bridge at that step: one whose other endpoint is left of the medial line, and one whose other endpoint is right of it.  You should be able to choose either one.

If multiple points share the maximal `y` coordinate then there may be multiple possible choices of upper bridge; the longest of the alternatives, which contains all the others, is the most efficient choice (but any of them will work).